# Ruby + Rails: Loop logic for layout design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I use Rails often, but am not all that familiar with Ruby loops.  I need to do the following:

I am trying to create a layout where I loops through a list `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and generate a 3 column layout such that I end up with:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</div>
```

if the list was `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` I would want the following:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
</div>
```

How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`in_groups_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) as follows:

```
<% [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].in_groups_of(3).each do |group| %>
  <div class='col-md-4'>
    <% group.each do |elem| %>
      <li><%= elem -%></li>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

which produces:

```
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
</div>
```

Comment: my only issue (which I didn't state) is that my list is really made up of dictionaries and when I try to do `<li><%= elem[:name] %></li>` I get a no method error for nil class `[]`.  When my dictionary includes `{"name": "foo"}`

Comment: after reading the docs, the error was occurring becasue I needed to include `in_groups_of(3, false)` since the list length is not always divisible by 3

Comment: @JeremyThomas, very well.

Answer (score 0):

[each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) allows you to grab a certain number of elements from an array, then do something with them.

E.g.: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].each_slice(3).map{|i| i} 
    => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

Edit: @vee's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36184638/385532) is much nicer due to the `fill_with` param, check the documentation!